# System.StackOverflowException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

I am facing an issue with entityframework. There is no recursive loop exist in the query but i do not know why i am facing this exception. You can see the code.

```
    var checkList = from checklist in db.Checklists
                        join code in db.Codes on checklist.iCodeID equals code.iCodeID
                        where code.bDeleted == false && code.bObsolete == false
                        join codeGroup in db.CodeGroups on code.iGroupID equals codeGroup.iGroupID
                        where codeGroup.bDeleted == false && codeGroup.bInspection == true
                        join codeInspectionType in db.CodeInspectionTypeVs on checklist.LongKey.Substring(0, 6) equals DbFunctions.Right("00000" + codeInspectionType.InspectionTypeID, 6)
                        where checklist.bDeleted == false
                        orderby checklist.iChecklistID
                        select new
                        {
                            checklist.iChecklistID,
                            InspectionTypeID = checklist.LongKey.Substring(0, 6).ToString(),
                            codeInspectionType.bSubInspection,
                            SortSeq = db.CodesTreeSelectUDF(null, checklist.LongKey, null, null, null).Select(x => x.SortKey).FirstOrDefault(),
                            codeGroup.iGroupID,
                            codeGroup.GroupDesc,
                            checklist.bPromptForQty,
                            checklist.bShowInTree,
                            DescCombo = new { codeGroup.DescCombo1, codeGroup.DescCombo2, codeGroup.DescCombo3, codeGroup.DescCombo4, codeGroup.DescCombo5, codeGroup.DescCombo6, codeGroup.DescCombo7, codeGroup.DescCombo8, codeGroup.DescCombo9, codeGroup.DescCombo10, codeGroup.DescCombo11, codeGroup.DescCombo12, codeGroup.DescCombo13, codeGroup.DescCombo14, codeGroup.DescCombo15, codeGroup.DescCombo16, codeGroup.DescCombo17, codeGroup.DescCombo18, codeGroup.DescCombo19, codeGroup.DescCombo20, codeGroup.DescCombo21, codeGroup.DescCombo22, codeGroup.DescCombo23, codeGroup.DescCombo24, codeGroup.DescCombo25, codeGroup.DescCombo26, codeGroup.DescCombo27, codeGroup.DescCombo28, codeGroup.DescCombo29, codeGroup.DescCombo30 },
                            codeGroup.DescText1,
                            codeGroup.bTextAbbreviation1,
                            codeGroup.DescText2,
                            codeGroup.bTextAbbreviation2,
                            codeGroup.DescText3,
                            codeGroup.bTextAbbreviation3,
                            codeGroup.DescText4,
                            codeGroup.bTextAbbreviation4,
                            codeGroup.DescText5,
                            codeGroup.bTextAbbreviation5,
                            codeGroup.DescText6,
                            codeGroup.bTextAbbreviation6,
                            codeGroup.DescText7,
                            codeGroup.bTextAbbreviation7,
                            codeGroup.DescText8,
                            codeGroup.bTextAbbreviation8,
                            codeGroup.DescText9,
                            codeGroup.bTextAbbreviation9,
                            codeGroup.DescText10,
                            codeGroup.bTextAbbreviation10,
                            codeGroup.DescInt1,
                            codeGroup.DescInt2,
                            codeGroup.DescInt3,
                            codeGroup.DescInt4,
                            codeGroup.DescInt5,
                            codeGroup.DescInt6,
                            codeGroup.DescInt7,
                            codeGroup.DescInt8,
                            codeGroup.DescInt9,
                            codeGroup.DescInt10,
                            codeGroup.DescNum1,
                            codeGroup.DescNum2,
                            codeGroup.DescNum3,
                            codeGroup.DescNum4,
                            codeGroup.DescNum5,
                            codeGroup.DescNum6,
                            codeGroup.DescNum7,
                            codeGroup.DescNum8,
                            codeGroup.DescNum9,
                            codeGroup.DescNum10,
                            codeGroup.DescBool1,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText1,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText1,
                            codeGroup.DescBool2,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText2,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText2,
                            codeGroup.DescBool3,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText3,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText3,
                            codeGroup.DescBool4,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText4,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText4,
                            codeGroup.DescBool5,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText5,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText5,
                            codeGroup.DescBool6,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText6,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText6,
                            codeGroup.DescBool7,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText7,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText7,
                            codeGroup.DescBool8,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText8,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText8,
                            codeGroup.DescBool9,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText9,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText9,
                            codeGroup.DescBool10,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText10,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText10,
                            codeGroup.DescBool11,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText11,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText11,
                            codeGroup.DescBool12,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText12,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText12,
                            codeGroup.DescBool13,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText13,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText13,
                            codeGroup.DescBool14,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText14,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText14,
                            codeGroup.DescBool15,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText15,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText15,
                            codeGroup.DescBool16,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText16,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText16,
                            codeGroup.DescBool17,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText17,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText17,
                            codeGroup.DescBool18,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText18,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText18,
                            codeGroup.DescBool19,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText19,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText19,
                            codeGroup.DescBool20,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText20,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText20,
                            codeGroup.DescBool21,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText21,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText21,
                            codeGroup.DescBool22,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText22,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText22,
                            codeGroup.DescBool23,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText23,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText23,
                            codeGroup.DescBool24,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText24,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText24,
                            codeGroup.DescBool25,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText25,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText25,
                            codeGroup.DescBool26,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText26,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText26,
                            codeGroup.DescBool27,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText27,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText27,
                            codeGroup.DescBool28,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText28,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText28,
                            codeGroup.DescBool29,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText29,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText29,
                            codeGroup.DescBool30,
                            codeGroup.BoolOnText30,
                            codeGroup.BoolOffText30,
                            DescMoney = new { codeGroup.DescMoney1, codeGroup.DescMoney2, codeGroup.DescMoney3, codeGroup.DescMoney4, codeGroup.DescMoney5, codeGroup.DescMoney6, codeGroup.DescMoney7, codeGroup.DescMoney8, codeGroup.DescMoney9, codeGroup.DescMoney10 },
                            DescDate = new { codeGroup.DescDate1, codeGroup.DescDate2, codeGroup.DescDate3, codeGroup.DescDate4, codeGroup.DescDate5, codeGroup.DescDate6, codeGroup.DescDate7, codeGroup.DescDate8, codeGroup.DescDate9, codeGroup.DescDate10 },
                            DescMemo = new { codeGroup.DescMemo1, codeGroup.DescMemo2, codeGroup.DescMemo3, codeGroup.DescMemo4, codeGroup.DescMemo5, codeGroup.DescMemo6, codeGroup.DescMemo7, codeGroup.DescMemo8, codeGroup.DescMemo9, codeGroup.DescMemo10 },
                            codeGroup.Bookmark,
                            codeGroup.bProtected,
                            codeGroup.bMultiPicklist,
                            codeGroup.Notes,
                            code.iCodeID,
                            LongKey = db.CodesTreeSelectUDF(null, checklist.LongKey, null, null, null).Select(x => x.LongKey).FirstOrDefault(),
                            code.CodeSortCode,
                            code.Description,
                            code.bDefault,
                            CodeCombo = new
                            {
                                code.CodeCombo1,
                                code.CodeCombo2,
                                code.CodeCombo3,
                                code.CodeCombo4,
                                code.CodeCombo5,
                                code.CodeCombo6,
                                code.CodeCombo7,
                                code.CodeCombo8,
                                code.CodeCombo9,
                                code.CodeCombo10,
                                code.CodeCombo11,
                                code.CodeCombo12,
                                code.CodeCombo13,
                                code.CodeCombo14,
                                code.CodeCombo15,
                                code.CodeCombo16,
                                code.CodeCombo17,
                                code.CodeCombo18,
                                code.CodeCombo19,
                                code.CodeCombo20,
                                code.CodeCombo21,
                                code.CodeCombo22,
                                code.CodeCombo23,
                                code.CodeCombo24,
                                code.CodeCombo25,
                                code.CodeCombo26,
                                code.CodeCombo27,
                                code.CodeCombo28,
                                code.CodeCombo29,
                                code.CodeCombo30
                            },
                            code.CodeText1,
                            code.CodeTextAbbreviation1,
                            code.CodeText2,
                            code.CodeTextAbbreviation2,
                            code.CodeText3,
                            code.CodeTextAbbreviation3,
                            code.CodeText4,
                            code.CodeTextAbbreviation4,
                            code.CodeText5,
                            code.CodeTextAbbreviation5,
                            code.CodeText6,
                            code.CodeTextAbbreviation6,
                            code.CodeText7,
                            code.CodeTextAbbreviation7,
                            code.CodeText8,
                            code.CodeTextAbbreviation8,
                            code.CodeText9,
                            code.CodeTextAbbreviation9,
                            code.CodeText10,
                            code.CodeTextAbbreviation10,
                            CodeInt = new { code.CodeInt1, code.CodeInt2, code.CodeInt3, code.CodeInt4, code.CodeInt5, code.CodeInt6, code.CodeInt7, code.CodeInt8, code.CodeInt9, code.CodeInt10 },
                            CodeNum = new { code.CodeNum1, code.CodeNum2, code.CodeNum3, code.CodeNum4, code.CodeNum5, code.CodeNum6, code.CodeNum7, code.CodeNum8, code.CodeNum9, code.CodeNum10 },
                            CodeBool = new
                            {
                                code.CodeBool1,
                                code.CodeBool2,
                                code.CodeBool3,
                                code.CodeBool4,
                                code.CodeBool5,
                                code.CodeBool6,
                                code.CodeBool7,
                                code.CodeBool8,
                                code.CodeBool9,
                                code.CodeBool10,
                                code.CodeBool11,
                                code.CodeBool12,
                                code.CodeBool13,
                                code.CodeBool14,
                                code.CodeBool15,
                                code.CodeBool16,
                                code.CodeBool17,
                                code.CodeBool18,
                                code.CodeBool19,
                                code.CodeBool20,
                                code.CodeBool21,
                                code.CodeBool22,
                                code.CodeBool23,
                                code.CodeBool24,
                                code.CodeBool25,
                                code.CodeBool26,
                                code.CodeBool27,
                                code.CodeBool28,
                                code.CodeBool29,
                                code.CodeBool30
                            },
                            CodeMoney = new { code.CodeMoney1, code.CodeMoney2, code.CodeMoney3, code.CodeMoney4, code.CodeMoney5, code.CodeMoney6, code.CodeMoney7, code.CodeMoney8, code.CodeMoney9, code.CodeMoney10 },
                            CodeDate = new { code.CodeDate1, code.CodeDate2, code.CodeDate3, code.CodeDate4, code.CodeDate5, code.CodeDate6, code.CodeDate7, code.CodeDate8, code.CodeDate9, code.CodeDate10 },
                            CodeMemo = new { code.CodeMemo1, code.CodeMemo2, code.CodeMemo3, code.CodeMemo4, code.CodeMemo5, code.CodeMemo6, code.CodeMemo7, code.CodeMemo8, code.CodeMemo9, code.CodeMemo10 },
                            code.CodeURL,
                            code.SessionVariable,
                            code.bMandatory,
                            code.PopUp,
                            code.bDrillDown,
                            code.Icon
                        };
```

When i test this via postman it throws the following exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
```

I have searched about it but my case is different when i skip the select vales my query working normally. I do not know why. but without skip it throws exception.

Please help..

Comment: Sorry for saying this, but this query is insane. You should normalize your data model before even trying to bring this one step further. Subsequently, build the various parts of the UI in separate steps. Why do it all in one unmaintainable monolith?

Comment: Apart from that, `StackOverflowException`s are hard to spot without being able to run the code (and even then). But I'm pretty sure LINQ-to-SQL chokes in the amount of SQL code it's trying to generate.

Comment: @Gert Arnold What if this is the requirements from client. I know this is insane but how could i do for it.

Comment: @Gert Arnold IS there any other way to resolve this issue. As i mentioned. When i skip some fields from select statement it is become working fine. but for complete data it throws stackOverflow exception.

Comment: I already gave you some hints. Don't hide behind "requirements". It's up to you how to implement them technically.

Comment: Please give some detail of answer so that i can make your answer true. Thanks

Comment: Frankly, I don't know where to begin. Your source data, `Checklists`, `Codes`, etc., must be refactored first to remove all these repetitive properties and replace them by child records. For example, one `CodeGroup` having 30 `BoolOnText` child records, etc. etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of struggle i find answer by myself.

```
db.ConvertLongKeyUDF (LongKey) replace with
db.ConvertLongKeyUDF (LongKey) As ConvertedtLongKey


CodeGroup.Notes replace with
CodeGroup.Notes As codeGroupNotes


CodeGroup.bProtected replace with
CodeGroup.bProtected As codeGroup_bProtected


code.Notes replace with
codes.Notes As codeNotes


code.bProtected replace with 
codes.bProtected As code_bProtected
```

As these lines generating the same name fields which producing ERROR!